# How to use Box2d with Node.js on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, box2d

I have a server running Node.js. For that server I have used Box2d lib to simulated 2D physics. Looks like

```
npm install box2d
```

installs this: https://github.com/jadell/box2dnode But this is very obsolete and does not coincide with original Box2d API which was written in C++.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628078/which-box2d-javascript-library-should-i-use) people advice to use https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js but I am new to Node.js and I don't know how to use Box2D with Node. I have wrote

```
const Box2D = require('./js/box2d/Box2D_v2.3.1_min.js');
```

but his does not recognize `b2Vec2` type in here:

```
let gravity = new Box2D.b2Vec2(0, -9.81);
```

What is the correct way to use Kripek's box2d with Node.JS?

Comment: Maybe create an instance of Box2D? ```const box2D = new Box2D();```

Answer (score -1):

you might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/box2d
on how to use it

Comment: No this is for the version you get when you write `npm install box2d` but this version is shity. I want this version as advised in stackoverflow  https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js